# Pycaret models() method throw NameError

Tags: python, pycaret

If I try to execute:

```
from pycaret.regression import *
models()
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pycaret/regression.py", line 2088, in models
return pycaret.internal.tabular.models(
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pycaret/internal/tabular.py", line 9494, in models
logger.info(f"gpu_param set to {gpu_param}")
NameError: name 'logger' is not defined
```

Unable to fix so far....
Pycaret version is 2.3.4 installed in a new dedicated conda environment as suggested on Pycaret documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved!!

```
model()
```

has to be called necessary only after having defined a setup.
The following code works as expected:

```
reg = setup(df_work,
            target='CO',
            session_id=123,
            log_experiment=True,
            experiment_name=station,
            fold_strategy=TSSplit(train_size=30*24*7, n_splits=3),
            verbose=False,
            silent=True
            )
models()
```

Comment: Correct. The models that are enabled are dependent on the setup so they must be called after setup has been run.